# How to serve react components from express server using API calls

Tags: express, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making a project where the user will upload a `.jsx` file to the express server. In the backend it will be bundled using webpack and a `bundle.js` file will be generated.
Now from the next.js frontend on visiting a certain route, an API will be called and the express server will return the bundle file.

How to render the component in the next.js app?

Is there any other way to achieve this?

I tried using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it only shows the bundle file as text.